# How to make HTML Incremental Number

Tags: html, random, count, numbers, increment

excuse me if this is obvious, but i am an amateur.

I need to insert a forever incrementing (or counting) number into a piece of html code. Each time the page is loaded, the number should go up.

Whats the easiest way to do this?

Comment: The code varies on what language you are using.

Comment: This logic has to be runned by Client-side or Server-side?

Comment: Please provide more information. It is impossible to provide a good answer to this question

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify any language, so I'm just going to assume it's in JavaScript. I would save this variable in localstorage, then make it higher each time the page is visited. Localstorage can only save strings, so we have to take that into account.

```
document.onload = function(){ 
if(visit === undefined){
var visit = 0;
}
localStorage.setItem("visitCount", visit.toString());
localStorage.getItem("visitCount");
visit++;
document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = visit;
}
```

Using this method, we store a variable in localstorage and retrieve and update it each time the page is loaded. Hope this helps!

Comment: Note that this is client-side only. Every browser has its own counter and after clearing localstorage the counter will reset. Also LS is (mostly) persistent over restarting the browser, so maybe you want to use session?